# How to correctly align label to clarify information?

Tags: mobile, ios, labels

On the image below, that is NOT a button but juste a bubble to display information on a day planner, I'm trying to find the best way to align the labels **7h30mn today** and **30h this week**.

Currently, I aligned both labels to the right. Don't you think the durations are not well aligned and so not enough visible ? I actually do and I've already tried to left align labels.

Can anyone help me to enhance the user experience by improving my two labels design ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's no question - as study after study has shown - that lining up like data scans best. Don't be thrown off by the text "today" and "this week."

Hours (this week) could be lined up under hours (today) with the same for the minutes.

```
 7h 30mm
30h  0mm
```

That's if you want to keep the current formatting. I'm not certain that will test well. I would theorize that treating the time as one unit would work best.

```
 7:30
30:00
```

Whatever you choose - test.  The take away from this is to focus upon the placement or the relevant data.

Comment: You're right, I've been thrown off by the text 'today" and "this week". Anyway, thanks a lot for your response, I'll try different things :)